# D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners

Tags: java, android

I use Firebase to sign in users with their Google account in my app but it no longer works.

I've thought of many sources for this problem but haven't managed to figure it out. Updating Firebase SDKs to 9.2.1 didn't work and neither did setting them to 9.0.2. So what can the error be?

I haven't changed anything in the SignIn Activity and it used to work perfectly. I guess it has something to do with the 'Notified 0 auth state listeners' message. These are the screenshots made:

[image]

[image]